# Error: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized (Ubuntu 18.04, Gitlab)

Tags: android-emulator, gitlab-ci, ubuntu-18.04

I try start android emulator on Ubuntu 18.04 in Gitlab CI but get error. Please, help.

Gitlab output:

```
$ emulator -avd Android28 -no-snapshot-save &
$ export APK_PATH=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.../app-dev-debug.apk
$ mvn clean test
bash: строка 110: emulator: command not found
bash: строка 114: mvn: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

cmd output for gitlab-runner:

```
gitlab-runner@shafaci:/home/shafaci$ emulator -avd Android28
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: could not connect to display :0 ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/opt/platforms/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" even though it was found. ((null):0, (null))


Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))
```

Comment: Hi, has this been solved? I'm running into the same issue #ubuntu #emulator #qt